# Conditional formatting for cell based on self matches one from another column/tab/sheet using Apps Script

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, conditional-formatting

[UPDATED QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70661271/conditional-formatting-if-a-cell-matches-one-from-a-list-of-a-different-sheet-us)

[SOLUTION](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70673771/13333547)

I am looking for a better way to conditionally format a cell, if its contents match any cell from another column (in a different tab or sheet).

Edit: I need a solution that will not be overwritten by copy/paste of a new cell without CF rules.

The method I currently have in place is via Sheet's internal conditional formatting settings. However it isn't completely successful because rows are often <s>created and deleted</s> copy and pasted over the range, overwriting or breaking apart the range that the conditional rule is applied to. The conditional formatting rule I have tried is:

`=VLOOKUP(D2:D,INDIRECT("Blocked!$A$2:$A"),1,FALSE)=D2:D`

This works until I insert a new row into the range that it is applied on. It will then only be applied to D2:D5 and D7:D1000, etc, for a row created at 6. Over time this leads to 100's of conditional formatting rules and large gaps of to where it is being applied.

It is my understanding that this needs to be done with Apps Script, to be done completely, and I am not sure where to begin.

[Here is an example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T9VpINgvPax5nJpetIPPLUvE5fuiUPEQj69Nm7BZuWo/edit?usp=sharing)

Keeping the "Blocked" list of cells as a separate sheet would also be acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Should be pretty straightforward.  New tab on your shared sheet called MK.Idea with this cond. formatting rule:

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(D1,INDIRECT("Blocked!A:A"),0))
```

Note: Could you mention where you got/how you constructed your other attempt?  Appscript is definitely not necessary, And it would be good to correct the record at the source.

Comment: This answer does the same thing as my original solution. It is not maintained through copy/paste. I need a solution that is will not break under standard user expected manipulation (why I suggested Apps Script). Conditional formatting via Sheets rightfully removes CF rules if another rule or a cell with no rule is pasted over it. Edit: I will edit the original question to clarify.

Comment: I think I will delete this question and ask it again in a less convoluted way. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: ok.  I had no trouble when i try to copy and paste values into either list.

Comment: If you want to replicate the problem, create a new tab, click on a row number to select the whole row, copy, go to your sheet and paste. Unless you do Paste>Special>Values, it will overwrite CF rules on the underlying cells.

Comment: @Kevin Ah.  So your questions is just about pasting generally into a CF'ed range.  It isn't specific at all to the rule you're asking about.  I think the specificity in your question is actually a little misleading for folks unfortunately.

Comment: Agreed. Were you able to see the updated question link?

Comment: @Kevin I did.  There is no good way to do it.  Everyone just uses Paste>Values only as it's not a common use case. Pasting formatting along with values is the default because it's what most users want.