# Conditional formatting if a cell matches one from a list of a different sheet using Apps Script

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a changing list of numbers on a tab that I would like to apply conditional formatting to, if the cell is present in another list of numbers, on a different sheet.

[Potential Cities/Zip-Codes](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T9VpINgvPax5nJpetIPPLUvE5fuiUPEQj69Nm7BZuWo/edit?usp=sharing)

[List of Blocked Zip Codes](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qb8G3ZNp7O5QcAK4okV-ZdPIT0PtX_yEriwQICX9AHw/edit?usp=sharing)

I would like the zip codes on the main "Potential Cities" sheet, to be formatted when they are listed on the "Blocked Zip Codes" sheet.

The purpose is to create a formatting change that will very plainly show the user if a zip code they are trying to enter is blocked (or on the list). Normal conditional formatting does not work because copy/paste will overwrite CF rules. I also need to be able to apply the solution to multiple different sheets, that are all checking their cells against the list of blocked cells.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your goal from `The purpose is to create an alert / notify the user if a zip code they are trying to enter, is blocked (or on the list). Normal conditional formatting does not work because copy/paste will overwrite CF rules. I also need to be able to apply the solution to multiple different sheets, that are all checking their cells against the list of blocked cells.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: I am not sure but I think you have to first actually `IMPORTRANGE` to put the data onto you the sheet Potential Cities/Zip-Codes.

Comment: I’d try to make the custom menu that applies the plain conditional formatting on selected (or predefined) range. This way you can format the range any time you wish. For example — right after the copy paste operation. It can be done automatically with `onEdit()` trigger but I think it will work quite sluggish. Let me know if you need help with the code, and probably SO has the ready solutions already

Comment: @Tanaike If a cell in column A matches any cell from column B *of a different sheet*, then change color.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an [installable `onEdit()` trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#application_triggers) for your Potential Cities Spreadsheet which checks the Blocked Zips sheet for a match and applies some kind of formatting accordingly.

#### For example:

```
function checkForBlockedZips(e) {
  // do nothing if not column D
  if (e.range.getColumn() !== 4) return

  // get list of zips from blocked zips sheet
  const blockedZipsSsId = "your-spreadsheet-id"
  const blockedZipsSs = SpreadsheetApp.openById(blockedZipsSsId)

  const blockedZipsSheet = blockedZipsSs.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  const zipCodes = blockedZipsSheet.getRange("A2:A").getValues()
    .flat(2)
    .filter(x => x)

  // check if the entered value is in the list of blocked zips
  if (~zipCodes.indexOf(e.range.getValue())) {
    // create cell style
    const strikethrough = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle()
      .setStrikethrough(true)
      .build()
  
    const richText = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
      .setText(e.range.getValue())
      .setTextStyle(strikethrough)
      .build()
    
    // set the cell to have the desired rich text style
    e.range.setRichTextValue(richText).setBackground("yellow")
  }
  else {
    // if the value is not a blocked zip then reset the cell style 
    const nostrikethrough = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle()
      .setStrikethrough(false)
      .build()

    const richText = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
      .setText(e.range.getValue())
      .setTextStyle(nostrikethrough)
      .build()

    e.range.setRichTextValue(richText).setBackground("white")
  }
}
```

Things to note:

- You need to use `e.range.getValue()` instead of `e.value` so that copy/pasted values can be read
- You need to add this script to the Potential cities sheet and authorise it as an installable trigger

Comment: This works. Exactly as desired. It's a bit above my current level of familiarity and I'm going to dissect it to learn more. Thank you!